# R: exporting ggplot2 text gets super small

Tags: r, ggplot2, export, png

I made a graph with ggplot2 and in RStudio it looks really good. I also can export it manually. Unfortunately, when exporting it with code the text gets super small. I really need it to be exported by code.

**RStudio:**
[image]

**Code:**
[image]

```
Cairo::Cairo(
  1200, #length
  900, #width
  file = paste("cambridge_hashrate_countries_lollipop", ".png", sep = ""),
  type = "png", #tiff
  bg = "white", #white or transparent depending on your requirement 
  dpi = 300,
  units = "px" #you can change to pixels etc 
)

plot

logo <- image_read("../pics/logo_twitter-account.jpg")

grid::grid.raster(logo, x = 0.07, y = 0.03, just = c('left', 'bottom'), width = unit(0.5, 'inches'))
dev.off()
```

I also tried ggsave() same awful result.

How do I know what setting to choose to export it as RStudio?

Playing with dpi, height and width works, but then the labels are not properly displayed:

[image]

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "awful", but have you tried increasing the pixel density of your outputs, e.g. `ggsave(dpi = 320)`? You can also adjust the `height` and `width` of your plot in your call to `ggsave`

Comment: I think I has the same problem a few times ago. If i remember correctly you should try to plot it in R and then try to save it via save_plot(last_plot() )

Comment: Added the result when playing with dpi, height and width. How do I get the names properly displayed?

Comment: increase I haven't used that cairo argument but with 300 dpi i get publication grade graphics both pdf and png

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work. When I use dpi 300 the text gets very small as seen in the second image.

Answer (score 1):

I think you must use `png()` function.

Can you try something like that:

```
png(filename = 'path/t1.png', width = 930, height = 430)

ggplot(data=df)+
  geom_bar(mapping = aes('x','y'), stat = 'identity')

dev.off()
```

Comment: It does not work with the plot. The text is getting very small compared to the plot.